# Basic Loan calculator

Tags: python, calculator

I know I'm being a bit daft, but I've been trying to get this simple bit of code ( part of a computing project ) to be rounded to the 2nd decimal place and so far i haven't been able to do so.

```
   loan = float(input("Please enter Amount that you would like to borrow (£):"))
loanduration = float(input("Please enter Duration of the loan(Months):"))


print("You will pay (£)" ,loan/loanduration, "per month")



It outputs like so  
Please enter Amount that you would like to borrow (£):4000
Please enter Duration of the loan(Months):12
You will pay (£) 333.3333333333333 per month
>>>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
loan = float(input("Please enter Amount that you would like to borrow (£): "))
loanduration = float(input("Please enter Duration of the loan(Months): "))
print("You will pay (£) %.2f per month" % (loan/loanduration))
```

**Example usage:**

```
Please enter Amount that you would like to borrow (£):  4000
Please enter Duration of the loan(Months):  12
You will pay (£) 333.33 per month
```

Try it **[here!](https://repl.it/Fqds/1)**

Comment: Thank you for helping me with this as it was a late night and i completely forgot about that